# Kullback-Leibler Divergence of Stationary Distributions of Markov chains

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, markov-chains

Consider two finite Markov chains on the same state space, both assumed to be irreducible, with transition matrices $P$ and $Q$ and associated stationary distributions $\pi$ and $\tilde \pi$. Is it possible to bound the Kullback-Leibler divergence
$$ D_{KL}(\pi || \tilde \pi) = \sum_i \pi_i(\log  \pi_i - \log  \tilde\pi_i)
$$
or for that matter any other divergence in terms of the transition matrices $P$ and $Q$?

I am aware of work that bounds $\|\pi - \tilde \pi\|_\infty$ in terms of $P$ and $Q$, for example by Cho \& Meyer, Linear Algebra Appl. (2001).

Comment: The stationary distribution isn't a continuous function of the stochastic transition matrix. Imagine two matrices $P$ and $Q$ with two absorbing states. $P$ has a tiny probability to transition into the first state but a zero chance of transitionning into the second state whereas $Q$ has a tiny probability of transitionning into the second, but no chance of transitioning into the first.

This doesn't mean it's not possible to express a bound in terms of $P$ and $Q$, but it's not a good sign.